# How to solve the "cold start" problem for recommender systems?

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose you’re engineering a recommender system, what are some methodology for the cold start problem. For example, if you have a new user or a new item, how do you embed it?

If you learn embeddings, for example using matrix factorization, then a new item is presented with data points like movie length, director name, year, etc. How can you get strategically get data needed for better embeddings?

Comment: Isn't your best chance to enhance exploration if you really do not have any other information?

Comment: Lyle Unger, Wharton, patented and wrote some of the original RSs twenty-plus years ago for early big tech players. Amazingly, the field hasn't really advanced much since. Here's a link to one...https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/564376.564421

Comment: I think your problem statement is unclear: while you have information about a new item (maybe a movie) you will not have any information about a new user. For a new item you could simply embed it (e.g. the video) and then propose whatever worked on a similar item. For a new user which you do not know anything about you need to explore its preferences ...

Comment: @Ggjj11 I noted matrix factorization, this would require that user-item affinity matrix is available and then embeddings could be inferred for users and items, respectively. A new user or item will have characteristics but these have no relation to embeddings from matrix factorization. Hence the cold start problem exists and needs a solution.

Comment: @Ggjj11 In some cases you’ll have *a little* information about a user. For instance, you might have the date of birth, gender, or their address, so you can build a model that makes recommendations on the basis of age, gender, or location. It’s not necessarily related to the matrix factorization or embeddings, but it could provide better predictions than simple global predictions (“here’s a popular movie”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These days, you would never use matrix factorization for recommender systems. See ["The YouTube Video Recommendation System" by
James Davidson et al.](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=e7d53f538f5239739d1f943c81d17e4a167c65c6) for a very basic outline of the Youtube recommendation system.

One key thing to note from these two stage systems is that they generally use a deep learning model for the final ranking system. This allows the flexibility to use a viewer/video embedding, but also *any* feature that may be generated. So one can also use a channel embedding, topic, country, or any other metadata available to improve the recommendation in the case where we need to cold start a video/viewer. You can also use computer vision methods to extract topics from a video before any viewer engagement data is collect.

Similarly, the first stage of the recommendation system may use whatever model they want, such as a [two tower model](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval). So with these models, it is again possible to use some sort of metadata to improve recommendation compared to the random distribution you would need to do with a very simple matrix factorization model for new viewers/videos.

With that said, these systems still tend to favor distribution of established content over new content. As such, there has been recent work, such as ["Exploration in Recommender Systems" by
Minmin Chen](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3460231.3474601) on *forcing* the recommendation system to explore new content with a small portion of traffic.